# Не могу прочесть изображение в Eclipse Swing

Tags: java, swing

у меня не получается прочесть изображение, вылазит очень много ошибок в консоли.

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class InfoFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InfoFrame frame = new InfoFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public InfoFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{154, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                Image scaledImg = img.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                g2d.drawImage(scaledImg, 0, 0, this);
            }
        };  
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panel.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(panel, gbc_panel);
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setText("\u0420\u043E\u0437\u0440\u043E\u0431\u043D\u0438\u043A \u043F\u0440\u043E\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043C\u0438:\r\n\u0406\u0432\u0430\u043D\u0435\u043D\u043A\u043E \u041E\u043B\u0435\u0433 \u0406\u0433\u043E\u0440\u043E\u0432\u0438\u0447\r\n\u0421\u0442\u0443\u0434\u0443\u0435\u043D\u0442 \u041A\u0411-201\r\nivanenko197878@yahoo.com\r\n");
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_textArea.gridx = 0;
        gbc_textArea.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(textArea, gbc_textArea);
    }
    private URL url = InfoFrame.class.getResource("src/Photo.jpg");
    private BufferedImage img = null;
    {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Ошибки в консоли:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at view.InfoFrame.<init>(InfoFrame.java:87)
    at view.InfoFrame$1.run(InfoFrame.java:33)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: `private URL url = InfoFrame.class.getResource("src/Photo.jpg");` убедитесь что данный ресурс существует. У вас он `null`

Comment: В структуре видно, что он есть. Но могу попытаться это проверить, как это реализовать?

Comment: Только вы положили файл в src, а грузить пытаетесь ресурсы, которых там отродясь не было. Проверить это легко, запустите в режиме отладки и посмотрите значение переменной `url` после загрузки ресурса

Comment: В откладчике действительно url = null, но тогда какой я путь должен указать?

Comment: уберить src из строки "src/Photo.jpg"

Comment: у вас должен быть каталог `src\main\resources` в него обычно складываются ресурсы